# Import issues with ant in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, ant

I have checked out a open source java repository and imported it in IntelliJ. It uses ant for build purpose.

In build.xml I can see some dependencies mentioned. And 'ant' command runs successfully. But in code files, I see imports for those dependencies marked as red, meaning not available.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't support importing from Ant like it does for Maven, Gradle and SBT.

The only way is to [add the jar dependencies manually](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies).